# TopLayoutGuide spacing set to 0 creates empty space

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I am creating UI in xcode. I have added imageView which topLayoutGuide vertical spacing is set to 0. So I think that it should be positioned right under status bar. However it is positioned under navigation bar (which is not even present).
[image]

In the same storyboard I have some views that are embed in navigation controller and it is set to transculent=NO. But this view isnt even linked to them. So I dont think that this should be a problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the view debugger? See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: using vie debugger I have figured out that my ImageView was bigger than image inside it so using Aspect Fit it got centered and "missaligned". I have fixed this but I still need to set topLayoutGuide spacing to -20 to move view under status bar. Is this good aproach or I have som bad settings in app?

Comment: If you want the image under the status bar, use superview.top instead of the topLayoutGuide. The layout-guide is positioned at the bottom of the statusbar when it is visible and there is no navigation bar.